How can I find measurable sets aribtrarily close to a given set?
Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure set. It is well-known that $\mu$ defines an outer measure $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(X)\longrightarrow[0,+\infty]$ by
$$\mu^*(S) = \inf\,\{\mu(E)\;|\; E\in\mathcal{M},\;E\supseteq S\}.$$
I am trying to understand the proof of this fact. Specifically, at the time of showing $\sigma$-subadditivity, every proof I have seen makes the assumption that, given a sequence of subsets $(S_n)$ such that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mu^*(S_n)<+\infty,$$
it is possible, for every $\epsilon>0$ and every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, to find a measurable set $E_n\in\mathcal{M}$ such that
$$\mu(E_n) < \mu^*(S_n) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}.$$
However, I can't see a reason of principle why such measurable sets should necessarily exist. What if I chose $(S_n)$ as a sequence of non-measurable sets? Wouldn't it be conceivable to find some non-measurable set so pathological that one cannot find measurable sets whose measures are arbitrarily close to its outer measure?

There is nothing deep here, it follows directly from the definition of $\inf$.
In general if $m = \inf A$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $a \in A$ such that $a < m + \varepsilon$. Indeed, suppose for contradiction that $m + \varepsilon \leqslant a$ for all $a \in A$. Then $m+\varepsilon$ is a lower bound of $A$ which is greater than $m$, contrary to the definition of $m$ as the greatest lower bound.
Applying this to the definition of outer measure
$$\mu^*(S) = \inf \{ \mu(E) : E \in \mathcal{M}, E \supseteq S \},$$
for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $E \in \mathcal{M}$ with $E \supseteq S$ such that $\mu(E) < \mu^*(S) + \varepsilon$.

what if $A$ had an isolated point? For example $A={0}\cup [1,2]$

Also, the inequality direction and the sign in front of the $\epsilon$ are not quite what I'm looking for...

@KhalidWenchaoYjibo Sorry, I suddenly got busy before I could post-check the answer. I corrected a few typos.

thank you for making time to amend your answer, but I'm not fully convinced by the argument. For $A$ as in my comment above and $\epsilon=1/2$, the statement in the second paragraph of your answer is false.

For your example we have $m = \inf A = 0$. Given $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, I put forth $a = 0 \in A$ and get $0 < 0 + \frac{1}{2}$, which is true - what do you think is wrong? Anyway, I included a clarification in the second paragraph why the property holds. @KhalidWenchaoYjibo

My bad, I was not considering that you can have $a=m$ when $m\in A$...thanks for the extra clarification by contradiction, I'm convinced now.
